# Send computer icon to iPhone via Bonjour

Tags: iphone, image, icons, bonjour

OK.  So I've been researching this for the past two hours, but I've yet to find a solution.  I am currently developing a Mac server application and an iPhone client app with which it can interface.  What I am trying to do is simple: Send the computer icon from the server to the iPhone.  And by computer icon I mean the icon that you see when you go to the Finder, select your computer from "Devices," and "Get Info."  The big version of that icon.  After searching on Google I found that `[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer]` returns the image I am looking for.  So I tried sending the image data returned by `TIFFRepresentation` to the client and then creating a `UIImage` with the TIFF data, but when I then draw the recreated image in an image view, it ends up being the smaller version of the computer icon.  I don't know a lot about NSImage but I do know that using `setSize:` only sets the size for when you draw the image.  So if anybody knows how to obtain the large version of the computer icon and recreate that in a UIImage I would very much appreciate if you shared that knowledge with me.  I would like to figure this out as soon as possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your NSImage to a CGImageRef and then set the size you want. This code works on Snow Leopard (10.6.6) - not sure in older versions:

```
NSImage *computerImage = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer];
NSRect computerImageRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 512, 512);
CGImageRef computerImageCG = [computerImage CGImageForProposedRect:&computerImageRect 
                                                           context:nil hints:nil];
```

Best,

-Gabriel

Comment: So once I get a CGImageRef, what do I do then?  Sorry for my ignorance.  I really know nothing when it comes to images.

Comment: @EJV if you still want to send the image in TIFF: `[[[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:computerImageCG size:NSMakeSize(computerImageRect.width, computerImageRect.height)] TIFFRepresentation]`

Comment: Arg.  It still does not work.  :(  I'm definitely not getting the 512x512 version of the image.  I used your code to convert the NSImage into a CGImage and then back again, but to no avail.